# Simple expression calculator in C - stacks' application

Tags: c, stack, calculator

> Write a program that solves arithmetic expressions, passed as a string, printing its value. Use two stacks, one for operands and one for operators. Consider only + and * operators. Also consider 1-digit operands. Consider operator precedence in solving the expression.

My code is not working, but I cannot see the problem, even though I am looking for it for days. I really appreciate some help!

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>
# include<string.h>
# define MAX 40

int *p1, *p2; // pointers rows operands, operators
int *to1, *to2; // tops rows operands, operators
int *bo1, *bo2; // bases rows operands, operators

void push1(int i), push2(char j); //operating, operator - stack
int pop1(void), pop2(void); //operand, operator - unstack

void push1 (int i)
{
    if (p1>bo1)
    {
        printf("Stack of operands full \n");
    }
    *p1=i;
    p1++;
}
void push2 (char j)
{
    if (p2>bo2)
    {
        printf("Operator stack full \n");
    }
    *p2=j;
    p2++;
}

int pop1()
{
    p1--;
    if (p1<to1)
    {
        printf("Empty operand stack \n");
        return 0;
    }
    return *p1;
}

int pop2()
{
    p2--;
    if (p2<to2)
    {
        printf("Empty operator stack \n");
        return 0;
    }
    return *p2;
}

void main()
{
    int a,b, c, result, i, st;
    char o, s[MAX];
    p1= malloc(MAX*sizeof(int)); //allocate memory stack 1
    p2= malloc(MAX*sizeof(char)); //allocate memory stack 2

    to1=p1;
    to2=p2;
    bo1=p1+MAX-1;
    bo2=p2+MAX-1;

    printf("Enter the expression\n");
    gets(s);
    st=strlen(s);

    push1(s[0]); //put the first digit
    for (i=0; i<(st-1)/2+1; i++)
    {push1(s[2*(i+1)]); //stack the next digit
     push2(s[2*i+1]); //stack the next operator
         if (s[2*i+1]=='*') //if it's multiplication...
         {
             a=pop1(); // get the last two digits
             b=pop1();
             o=pop2(); //delete the operator
             push1(a*b); // replace with product
         }
    }
        
    while(p1>to1)
         {
             a=pop1();
             b=pop1();
             c=a+b;
             push1(c);
         }

    result=pop1();
    printf("Result=%d", result);
}
```

Comment: what are all those 2* for? The looping down the string should be very simple, you have made its ultra complex

Comment: I am sorry if I cannot understand: the "complication" is because I'd like to separate the caracteres + , * and the numbers...

Comment: I get the error, I was using char and performing mathematical operations bewteen them. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 1):

walking down the input string should be simple

```
  for(int i = 0; i < st; i++){
      char next = s[i];
       ....
  }
```

why all that complicated 2* , -1, /2+1....?

Comment: I am sorry if I cannot understand: the "complication" is because I'd like to separate the caracteres + , * and the numbers... Do your code could separate? Thank you really much!

Comment: I get the error, I was using char and performing mathematical operations bewteen them. Thank you for the effort!

Comment: @Quiet_waters you need to pull each character as i sbow and inspect it, is it a digit, if so add it to the current number, is it whitespace, if so tweminalte the current number and push it skip it, is it an operation, if so push terminate number, push number then pus operation......